# CGPointMake in the ViewDidApear (swift)

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

**first question:**
I have got a label in the middle of the screen in the main storyboard and i added some constraints,
I wanted to locate the label to y + 400 so i did this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    gamestopedLabel.center = CGPointMake(gamestopedLabel.center.x, gamestopedLabel.center.y + 400)
}
```

but everytime the view is loaded, it take half a second to make it "disappear" to the y+400.
I wanted to know how can it be fixed.

**seconds question:**
I have made a gesture recognizer for a double tap on the view - and when the user double tap the label come back to the center. But when he keep tapping twice the label is coming over and over to the center. I wanted to know how to disable the option so the user won't be able to click it again.

Thank you!

Comment: You should open a new question with your second question and in that second question show the code associated with your gesture recognizer.

Comment: Ok my bad :) I'll do it.